# Requesting help to proceed with interfacing my device with voice commands

Tags: node.js, websocket, home-automation

I have created a smart switch using NodeMcu Esp8266 wireless chip and programmed Websocket to create a TCP protocol to communicate. I wanted to know how should I proceed to interface this with google assistant and host my app on home control settings on Google assistant app?

Answer (score 0):

[Google's SDK for android google assistant](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/overview)

[Here if you are connecting to a Google Home](http://nilhcem.com/android-things/google-assistant-smart-home)

Comment: Thanks for the link .... could you explain me the entire process step by step ...it would be extremely helpful .. thankyou